# How to select a list in MySQL that excludes a specific item ID in a many to many relationship table?

Tags: mysql

I have a list of courses available in a MySQL table called `cursos`.
And I have a list of all students in a table called `usuarios`.
And to know which user is enrolled in which course (it's a many-to-many relationship) I have a `cursosUsuarios` table.

I want to show the user a list of all available courses for him/her to pick up a new course to enroll. But I don't want to show in that list the courses where the user already is enrolled in.

So, I thought about this, for example, to show all available courses where the user UID 1 is NOT in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cursos.cursoID, cursos.nombreCurso
FROM cursos LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios
ON cursos.cursoID = cursosUsuarios.cursoID
WHERE cursosUsuarios.userID != 1
GROUP BY cursosUsuarios.cursoID
```

This is the intended result:
`User 1` belongs to `Curso D` (id. 8), so, the list should not show the `Curso D`.

```
cursos.cursoID ---------- cursos.nombreCurso
5 -------------------------- Curso A
6 -------------------------- Curso B
7 -------------------------- Curso C
```

But the list shows every single course, (even `Curso D`) because there are other students enrolled in that course, so, in the table, the `curso D` ID does appear in other rows as well, even if the user ID 1 is not there.

This is what I've got in cursosUsuarios:

```
cursosUsuarios.cursoID ---------- cursosUsuarios.userID
8 ------------------------------------ 1
6 ------------------------------------ 2
7 ------------------------------------ 4
8 ------------------------------------ 3
6 ------------------------------------ 5
5 ------------------------------------ 2
```

So, the curso D (id. 8), has other users enrolled besides userID 1, so, that's why it does appear in the list, because of the row where the user ID is 3.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, just in case it helps someone:

I just need to do a subselect query, where the second query shows all courses where user ID 1 in enrolled, and then, the first select query contain a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cursos.cursoID, cursos.nombreCurso
FROM cursos LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios
ON cursos.cursoID = cursosUsuarios.cursoID

WHERE cursos.cursoID 
NOT IN (SELECT cursoID from cursosUsuarios WHERE userID = 1)
```